# Discord.js v.12 Invalid destructuring assignment target

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to learn discord.js and I just follow an example code that I found but it errors. This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
    var generalChannel = client.channels.cache.get("I already put the valid ID")
    generalChannel.send("C'mon dude")
    
    console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag)

    client.user.setActivity("Youtube", {Type: "WATCHING"})

    client.guilds.cache.forEach(("guild") => {
        console.log(guild.name)
        guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
            console.log('  ${channel.name} ${channel.type} ${channel.id}')
        })
    })
})

client.login("I already put valid token")
```

This is the error message:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target
```

Please tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you try to use a string in `("guild")`. See the double quotes around `guild`? You don't need them as you want to use the `guild` variable. You can try this instead:

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    console.log(guild.name)
    guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
        console.log('  ${channel.name} ${channel.type} ${channel.id}')

    })
})
```

Comment: Also, remember you can add async, and remove the ()s around "guild" since it’s the only parameter